Internal Server Error while trying to read data from the database
I am trying to read data from MongoDB, but while doing so, I am getting -
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
Here is how I am trying to read the data -
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        let config = {
            method: "get",
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "journals",
            headers: {
                Authorization: localStorage.getItem("Token"),
            }
        };

        axios
            .request(config)
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data.journals);
                console.log("Data read from database")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error in reading data", error);
            });
    }, []);

The controller for backend is also set up properly -
exports.getJournals = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("trying to get journals")
    try {
        let query;
        // If user is an admin, return all journals
        if (req.user.role === 'admin') {
            query = Journal.find();
        } else {
            // If user is a member, only return their own journals
            query = Journal.find({ owner: req.user._id });
        }

        const journals = await query;

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            count: journals.length,
            journals
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: err
        });
    }
};

But the line "trying to get journals" is not being logged.
The routes for the same is also set properly -
server.js -
app.use('/api/journals', require('./routes/Journal'));

router-
router.route('/').get(getJournals);


Try logging url before the axios call, and then use curl or a browser to test it.
